# Word for piece of furniture in the hall/lobby for storing shoes

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, translation

What is the proper word to refer to a piece of furniture in the hall/lobby for storing shoes?

In Russian we use the word "тумбочка" which can be translated as bedside-table, just adding "shoes/for shoes" to it ("обувная тумбочка"). But obviously bedside table doesn't fit for referring to "piece of furniture in the hall/lobby for storing shoes" in English. What is the proper name for this piece of furniture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shoerack.

E.g. http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/categories/departments/hallway/10454/
That page also has "shoe storage" but real people don't say that in conversation.

Comment: That is what we call ours, which adds further confirmation to me that you are a UK chap.

Comment: _Shoe rack_ is common in UK at least or in my case; floordrobe.

Comment: @WS2: [You are entirely correct, old chap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xAeSkdtaeI).

Comment: We are Americans, and we have a shoe rack in the entry.

Answer (score 2):

*Lobby shoe cabinet or shoe storage* may be an appropriate definition:

[Shoe cabinet](https://www.google.it/search?q=shoe%20cabinet&biw=768&bih=928&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=_lheVN-xAYrfoATjpYC4BA&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQsAQ):

Comment: Doesn't a shoe cabinet need doors?

Answer (score 0):

I recently listened to a British radio show where they used the phrase “shoe tidy” to describe this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I guess it would be useful to indicate radio show in question and/or phrase used if possible.